# PHP:How can I send the Data entered by a user in a text field to a txt file?

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP How can I send the Data entered by a user in a text field to a txt file  inside of a folder on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the file and open for writing:

```
$h = fopen("path and filename", "wb+");
```

or appending:

```
$h = fopen("path and filename", "ab+");
```

To write to the file:

```
fwrite($h, $myString);
```

Then close it:

```
fclose($h);
```